# Swift Message IBM MQ Testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

IBM MQ testing I  am using the code which is in Internet, only thing which I am getting stuck is how to handle message in the below given code:
def producer = sess.createProducer(destination)

def payload = "your message here"
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

My payload is like below format:

```html
{1:10XXUGGDD} {2:XYCGDDYY} {4:
:16R:GENL
:20C::SEME//${time}--I will use time function
:23G:ABCD
:98A::PREP//${time}-I will use time function
.
.
.
-}
```

I am passing this value as string but I getting error "Unexpected Character : **":"**
I am not sure how to pass the message in same format to variable payload.

Can someone help me.

Thanks,
Akshat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what exactly you're trying to generate, try out the following syntax:

```
def payload = '{1:10XXUGGDD} {2:XYCGDDYY} {4:\n' +
        ':16R:GENL\n' +
        ':20C::SEME//' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '\n' +
        ':23G:ABCD\n' +
        ':98A::PREP//' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '\n' +
        '.\n' +
        '.\n' +
        '.\n' +
        '-}'

def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)
```

Demo of the approach working (at least not generating the error when being printed to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging))

[image]

Just in case:

- Documentation on [Groovy Strings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings)
- [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, its working, can we also encode this message as well??