# Swift Message IBM MQ Testing using Jmeter-Encode Message

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am sending message based on the format mention at [Swift Message IBM MQ Testing using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857868/swift-message-ibm-mq-testing-using-jmeter), but it is failing at Application End, because payload which we are sending in format of text, look we need to Encode the message as UTF-8 or ASCII.

def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

Can we send this payload in encoded form?

Thanks,
Akshat

Comment: Stop tagging your questions with `swift`, that tag is for the programming language Swift and not the financial messaging system Swift.

Comment: SWIFT exists for 50 years and Swift for how many? 5? 6? So maybe Swift programmers should look for their own tag instead?

Comment: We have our own tag and since this is a site primarily about programming I don’t see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the text message in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) you need to add the next line to your script:

```
msg.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1208)
```

More information:

- [JMS client message conversion and encoding](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=conversion-jms-client-message-encoding)
- [Codeset names and CCSIDs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=conversion-codeset-names-ccsids)
- [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)

Comment: thanks I added this after 'code' def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload), but I am getting error 'code'  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: WMQContants for class: Script16

Comment: If you like to copy and paste you can copy and paste this line to the beginning of your script: `com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants` however I would strongly recommend getting familiarized with [Groovy Program Structure](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html) and [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as this is not a code-writing service, no one is willing to do your job for you for free, you're getting paid for presumable ability to think and solve problems and not for copying and pasting ready solutions from the Internet